# Need help figuring out why vue-router isn't working for my simple tab control scenario

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, buefy

I have a very simple sample app with a tab control. I'd like either component A or component B to be displayed when a tab is selected. This should be handled by vue-router fairly easily but I don't know what's wrong with my config.

When I click on either tab button, nothing happens. None of my components display.

What am I missing?

### **main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import {
  Tabs,
} from 'buefy';
import 'buefy/dist/buefy.css';
import App from './App.vue';
import './registerServiceWorker';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';

Vue.use(Tabs);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

### **App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <section>
      <b-tabs type="is-toggle">
        <b-tab-item label="Component A" to="/ComponentA"></b-tab-item>
        <b-tab-item label="Component B" to="/ComponentB"></b-tab-item>
      </b-tabs>
    </section>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<style>
</style>
```

### **router\index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import ComponentA from '@/components/ComponentA.vue';
import ComponentB from '@/components/ComponentB.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/ComponentB',
    name: 'ComponentA',
    component: ComponentA,
  },
  {
    path: '/ComponentB',
    name: 'ComponentB',
    component: ComponentB,
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

### **components\ComponentA.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>Hello From Component A</div>
</template>
```

### **components\ComponentB.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>Hello From Component B</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an existing [issue](https://github.com/buefy/buefy/issues/443) with Tabs & Router in **Buefy**. You could do something like this:

```
<b-tabs>
    <router-link
        label="Component A"
        :to="{ name: 'ComponentA' }"
    >
        Component A
    </router-link>

    <router-link
        label="Component B"
        :to="{ name: 'ComponentB' }"
    >
        Component B
    </router-link>
</b-tabs>
```

Or use a Buefy component that supports Vue Router, e.g:

```
<b-button tag="router-link" to="/ComponentA" type="is-link">
    Component A
</b-button>
```